# Highway Patrol Problem Using Related Rates

Tags: calculus

A highway patrol plane flies 3 miles above a level, straight road at a steady 120mph. The pilot sees an oncoming car and with radar determines that at the instant the line of sight distance from plane to car is 5 miles, the line of sight distance is decreasing at the rate of 160mph. Find the car's speed along the highway.

Comment: What's confusing me is that they mention the rate of the plane. I know you would have to use the pythagorean theorem and incorporate the differentials, but it looks like you would have two different rates along the x axis.

Answer (score 1):

Let the horizontal position of the plane and car be $x_p,x_c$ respectively. Then we have the line of sight distance (in miles) at time $t$ is $l(t) = \sqrt{(x_p(t)-x_c(t))^2 + 3^2}$. Let $t=0$ be the moment the pilot takes the line of sight speed reading, then we have $l(0) = 5 = \sqrt{(x_p(0)-x_c(0))^2 + 3^2}$, hence we have by (Pythagoras) $x_p(0)-x_c(0) = \pm 4$. Since the problem says 'oncoming car' we may presume that, in fact, $x_p(0)-x_c(0) =  -4$.

We are also given $\frac{d l(0)}{dt} = -160$. The formula for $l$ gives $\frac{d l(t)}{dt} = \frac{x_p(t)-x_c(t)}{l(t)} (\frac{d x_c(t)}{dt} - \frac{d x_p(t)}{dt})$. Plugging in values gives: $\frac{d l(0)}{dt} = -160= \frac{x_p(0)-x_c(0)}{l(0)} (\frac{d x_c(0)}{dt} - \frac{d x_p(0)}{dt}) = \frac{-4}{5} ( 120 -\frac{d x_p(0)}{dt})$, from which you can figure out the required answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here, $c$ is this line of sight distance between the plane and the car, while $b$ is the horizontal distance between the car and the plane. The height of the plane is given as 3 miles.

The goal is the find the car's speed, using $\frac{db}{dt}$ and the plane's known speed. Since this forms a right triangle, with the Pythagorean Theorem, $b^2+9=c^2$. Deriving both sides we get $2b\frac{db}{dt}=2c\frac{dc}{dt}$.

It is given that when $c=5$, $b=4$ (it forms a 3, 4, 5 Pythagorean triple), and $c$ is decreasing at a rate of $-160$ mph. This can be written as $\frac{dc}{dt}=-160$ mph.

Plugging these values into our derived equation, we get:

$2(4)\frac{db}{dt}=2(5)(-160)$

$\frac{2(5)(-160)}{2(4)} = \frac{db}{dt} =-200$ mph

This gives us that the car and the plane are horizontally coming closer to each other at a speed of $200$ mph ($b$ is changing at a rate of $-200$ mph). Since it is given that the plane is travelling at $120$ mph, and the car is approaching it from the opposite direction, the car's speed must be $200=120+v$, or $80$ mph.